# Как реализовать парсинг криптопар в режиме реального времени

Tags: python, парсер

Нужно запарсить 3 криптовалюты с сайта (https://www.htx.com/trade/eth_usdt?type=spot), цены на них обновляются в режиме реального времени. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы если цена изменилась, обновлять её в парсере. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.